# AWS ssh public key denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

There are lot of questions and discussions regarding this. I tried to follow along the documentation as well but could not figure it out.

Basically I can ssh using my pem key
like `ssh -i "xyz.pem" ubuntu@ec2-134-13-11-45.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

But now I need to ssh it normally without pem, like `ssh ubuntu@ip`
It keeps showing as permission denied public key.

So I generated public key using keygen and pushed it to `.ssh/authorized_keys`  in server from local system by making a new dir `.ssh` in ubuntu instance, setting chmod 700 and chmod 600 permissions

Still whenver I try to access it directly `ssh@ubuntu.ip` I keep getting error..

This is a very basic question, please help me through this!

Comment: What's the goal here? Just to avoid having to specify which key to use? You could add it to your ssh-agent keyring via `ssh-add /path/to/xyz.pem`

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be mixing the 'sending' side and the 'receiving' side.

When initiating an SSH connection, you *must* send an SSH key. This can either be done via the `-i` option as you showed, or it can be configured as an [SSH alias](https://www.howtogeek.com/75007/stupid-geek-tricks-use-your-ssh-config-file-to-create-aliases-for-hosts/) by storing data in `.ssh/config`:

```yaml
Host foo
  User ec2-user
  HostName 54.1.2.3
  IdentityFile ~/xyz.pem
```

This then starts an SSH session with `ssh foo`.

On the *receiving* side, the public keypair must be stored in the user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. When Linux receives a request to connect via SSH, it checks that file for a matching keypair.

So, it looks like you did the right thing on the instance, but you need a configuration file on your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe aws servers are set up to use only ssh key files. If you want to be able to use a password edit

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

find `PasswordAuthentication no` and change to `yes`

make sure to reload ssh using `sudo systemctl reload ssh`

and you will be able to access the server without a ssh key file